# Controle de visualização via autorização com AngularJS + WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo construído com AngularJS e ASP.NET Web API. Por enquanto, usando o ASP.NET Identity já consegui implementar autenticação e autorização na API usando OAuth 2.0 e autorização baseada em tokens.

Testei com a api separadamente da interface e já pude ver que tudo funciona como esperado. Ainda estou com dúvida, porém, em como fazer com a parte AngularJS. Estou pensando agora na autorização.

O problema que eu tenho é o fato de nem todas as rotas serem permitidas e o fato da seleção de páginas não consultar o servidor, sendo feito diretamente por javascript. Dessa forma, apesar de eu ser capaz de bloquear o acesso a um controller no servidor eu não sei como fazer para bloquear o acesso as telas correspondentes no aplicativo JS.

A minha ideia foi basicamente criar um serviço capaz de escolher as rotas para o usuário e então retornar um array com os objetos correspondentes que poderia ser iterado e registrado no angular. Basicamente seria algo do tipo:

```
opcoes = {
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'servidor/api/rotas'
};

$.ajax(opcoes).then(function(dados) {
    angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider) {
        // itera pelos dados e para cada objeto adiciona a rota
    });
});
```

O problema é que não sei se essa é uma boa solução e de qualquer forma, parece que ela só iria servir pra definir as rotas certas, não sei se ainda haveria brechas de segurança.

Essa é uma boa solução para autorização no AngularJS? Existem jeitos melhores de se fazer isso, ou essa abordagem é suficiente?

Comment: Aqui na empresa nós colocamos toda a autenticação na webapi e enviamos uma lista de menus ou páginas disponíveis para o usuário. Caso algum usuário consiga acessar qualquer página que não deveria, o server deve retornar um 401 e o App vai redirecionar o usuário para tela de login ou home (dependendo do projeto).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que o caminho é por aí mesmo. Recentemente implementei algo parecido  (mas com KnockoutJS em vez de AngularJS), e nem me preocupei muito com essa questão de acesso, já que o bloqueio que importa mesmo estava devidamente implementado na WebAPI.

Como estamos falando de colocar as rotas diretamente no Javascript, é sempre importante lembrar que a "segurança" é relativa, já que qualquer pessoa pode olhar o seu código. Da forma como entendo, o que você quer fazer é apenas criar uma forma mais "amigável" de tratar acessos inválidos, correto?

Se sim, dê uma olhada nisso aqui, acho que pode ser útil. Me lembrou bastante o que você está pensando em fazer:
[Authentication in Single Page Applications With Angular.js](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)

Comment: Obrigado @MichaelSiegwarth. Esse artigo ajudou a dar umas ideias. É um pouco diferente do que eu estou fazendo, porque no meu caso as rotas em si realmente dependem do usuário, mas já deu uma ideia de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de implementar controles de processo e visibilidade. A implementação atual nos aplicativos com os quais trabalho é a seguinte:

- **Criação de um endpoint para obtenção das permissões *client-bound***

A idéia é fornecer à aplicação Angular as permissões públicas do usuário - algumas, restritas para uso no back-end, são ignoradas. O resultado final é similar ao seguinte exemplo:

> http://localhost/aplicacao/framework/auth/identity

Com o seguinte resultado sendo retornado:

```
{
    "Id":"324c915c-a59d-45f7-8005-03eac6d74b28",
    "Locator":"fakeuser",
    "Email":"fakeuser@domain.com",
    "Name":"Fake User",
    "permissionsKeys":[
        "USR",
        "ADM",
        "MSG",
        "AUDIT"
    ]
}
```

- **Parse da lista, e controle de visualicação de conteúdo *client-side***

Utilizando de uma biblioteca para checar a presença de uma dada permissão, é fácil implementar controle de visualização:

```
<div ng-if="auth.hasPermission('AUDIT')">Auditor</div>
```